# Is PhoneGap on iOS hard coded to load www/index.html?

Tags: ios, cordova

On PhoneGap on Android you can modify the App.java class to load any url. I can't find anywhere to change the entry point on the iOS version.

When testing I prefer to have a few "www" directories with different setups. At the moment I need to rename the directories which is a bit of a nuisance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

Create the default index.html and have it wrap and load your own html root file, that way you can keep your own directory structure and no need to do any modifications there.

Of course, phonegap is open source, so you could also commit a change to phonegap to change the iOS api similar to Android API. Currently it seems the root html file path is determined in class PhoneGapDelegate.m

Comment: Ah.. I see it now in PhoneGapDelegate.m. Ok that answers my question. And that's a nice workaround also. Top marks. Thanks Hannes.

Comment: For others.. the link to that file is [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-iphone/blob/master/PhoneGapLib/Classes/PhoneGapDelegate.m)

Comment: that link is now [here](https://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/blob/master/iphone/PhoneGapLib/Classes/PhoneGapDelegate.m)

Answer (score 14):

As of PhoneGap 2.2, you can now override the `<content>` tag in your `config.xml`:

```
<content src="http://www.example.com" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't we be able to set this in the default www/config.xml file? The changes don't carry over to each platform's config.xml files.

Answer (score 8):

PhoneGapDelegate.h defines a class method startPage which you can overload/redefine in your iOS app's AppDelegate.m file.

```
+ (NSString*) startPage;
```

For example:

```
+ (NSString*) startPage{ 
    return @"http://m.google.com";
}
```

Will redefine the start page in PhoneGap. You will have to add google.com to your ExternalHosts in PhoneGap.plist. As of PhoneGap 1.2 If you do this and include Plugins in your native app, remotely host PhoneGap apps and their related *.js WILL be able to preform plugin actions. I've tested this with BarcodeScanner, ChildBrowser and ApplicationPreferences.

**UPDATE**

As of 1.4.0 and 1.4.0, startPage and wwwFolderName are properties instead of methods. They are still redefinable, but you can no longer have startPage point to a remote (non-local) phonegap installation like in my above example. (Which is kind of a bummer)

Comment: yes a bummer, i also read apple will reject your app if the code is hosted remotely, true?  is there an alternative to getting remote to work and apple not rejecting it?

Comment: As I understand it, that is no longer the case, and the code they mention is native code, not javascript code running in a UIWebView. There are numerous examples that do this.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it

class/ AppDelegate.m

change self.viewController.startPage to ur startpage in AppDelegate.m