# Launching Custom URL in PhoneGap + iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova, sencha-touch

I am developing Sencha touch application that will work on iPhone. Now application is ready and works fine in phone browser. But, now I want to distribute my application so I am using PhoneGap.

All my HTML and JavaScript pages are deployed at **http://170.60.26.20:8099/Sencha/Html/index.html**. Now i want to load that URL using phonegap. Suggest me the steps how could I do this.

I have installed phonegap-1.2.0-0 version.

Comment: @iMayur..  i have tried the way u explained just by changing window.location="http://170.60.26.20:8099/Sencha/Html/index.html";   but it is not working still..

Comment: Your url http://170.60.26.20:8099/Sencha/Html/index.html not working in normal browser because the server where this page is located isn't responding.

Comment: @iMayur.. in my testing environment. i am hitting the url in mobile browser. it is working fine that means that URL is absolutely fine.  just that it is not working on phone-gap.

Comment: I have tried in Mobile Browser (Simulator and Device too), still http://170.60.26.20:8099/Sencha/Html/index.html url is not responding. will you please provide working url like I have used demo link in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xcode , start a new project as phonegap project. Then copy the files from your project folder to **www** folder in the phonegap project.Keep in mind that index.html file should be in the parent folder , otherwise you have to change the url accordingly  in the corresponding class that invokes a webview.

You can follow this link

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20iOS%20using%20Xcode%204

Hope it will help

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. but my all html and js resources are present in remote server. how could i load that. in android we use loadUrl() given by phonegap sdk. how could i do the same here.

Comment: Check with this URL also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063802/is-phonegap-on-ios-hard-coded-to-load-www-index-html great solution just overload  `+ (NSString*) startPage;` in AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 4):

Create new Phonegap App in xcode and you just need to modify already exist `index.html` file in `www` folder.
You can use `window.location` javascript method to load your web app in phone app.

In PhoneGap(Cordova).plist, add your server to the `ExternalHosts` list and make `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `YES`.

Please try following code to run your html pages in phonegap app.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Change this if you want to allow scaling -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=default-width; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>LoadUrl
    <!-- If you application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onBodyLoad()
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }
    /* When this function is called, PhoneGap has been initialized and is ready to roll */
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
    // do your thing!
       window.location="http://web.me.com/djpinter1/iPhone/jqtouch/demos/main_tabbar/#ui";
      //window.location="http://170.60.26.20:8099/Sencha/Html/index.html";
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add your server to the ExternalHosts list and OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES in PhoneGap.plist, otherwise the new page will open in Safari.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.  This helped me figure out the problem I was having.